# Arrow-Key (left) gets stuck

Tags: keyboard

Sometimes my Arrow-Key Left gets stuck. It seems like it would just spam the key and dont accepts any others keys anymore. I can't even activate/deactivate the Numpad with the "Num"-Key
I need to force the shutdown with the Power-Button. After restart it works without any problems.

Anyone knows a fix for this?
Or anyone knows a way how to find out what causes the problem?

Laptop: Lenovo ThinkPad L15 G2 (Intel)
Ubuntu: 20.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking you will have to replace the key or maybe the whole board. On my gateway laptop, I was able to purchase a new key mechanism to replace the bad one.